# How to force to show all notifications of MS Defender Firewall via GPO?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, group-policy, notifications

I am preparing a set of GPO to harden W10. I enabled the Defender firewall blocking most of the connections but I also wanted to leave the notifications for helping me with the fine tuning of the settings. So I can get feedback of flows and applications that might need to be allowed.
[Firewall notification message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ro0gS.png)

I already tried with the following settings

> - Computer Configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security   Private Profile\Settings          Display a notification      YES
> - Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates         Network\Network Connections\Windows Defender Firewall\Domain Profile     Windows Defender Firewall: Prohibit notifications               Disabled
> - Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates         Windows Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications            Hide all notifications                                                                          Disabled
> - Computer Configuration / Policies / Admin templates         Windows Components\Windows Defender Security Center\Notifications            Hide non-critical notifications                                                            Disabled

and the setting appears grey out with the message "this setting is managed by your system administrator". But the notification appears set to off(!).
 [Firewall notification settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxPb6.jpg)
Any idea why this could happen? is there any other setting I should tweak to achieve my goal?

Many thanks.

Comment: We are always glad to help, but a question of this nature would probably be more appropriate within the [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) community.

Comment: very true. I will post it there inmediately. sorry!